# SQL pyodbc for strings

Tags: sql, sql-insert, pyodbc

Trying to add the following command using `pyodbc` :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable](ID,FileID,Description) 
VALUES(1, 1, "Imported from 'MyTestfile.txt'");
```

I get the error:

> "Invalid Column name" for the "Description" which was created as a "varchar(2048)".

Comment: String constants are enclosed in single quotes in SQL, double quotes are for identifiers ("names")

Comment: I need the resulting text to look like that as "Imported from 'MyTestfile.txt'" hence looking at how this would be used in the SQL command

Comment: Try `, 'Imported from ''MyTestfile.txt''');`.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Apologies for the late reply.